# Bootstrap 3 popover & tooltip on same element - tooltip doesn't fire

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to simply add a popover and tooltip to an element, each with different content.

The popover works as it should but the tooltip doesn't fire.

Here's what I'm trying:

**HTML**

```
<div 
  class="myPopover" 
  data-html="true" 
  popover-title="<h4>title popover</h4>" 
  popover-content="msg popover" 
  data-tooltip="tooltip" 
  title-tooltip="<h4>Title tooltip</h4>mesage in tooltip"
>
  hover / click me
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var toolTipSettings = {
  trigger: 'hover',
  container: 'body',
  placement: 'left',
  title: function(){
    return $(this).attr('title-tooltip');
  }
}

var popOverSettings = {
  trigger: 'click',
  placement: 'bottom',
  container: 'body',
  selector: '.myPopover',
  title: function(){
    return $(this).attr('popover-title');
  },
  content: function () {
    return $(this).attr('popover-content');
  }
}

$('body').popover(popOverSettings);
$('[data-tooltip="tooltip"]').tooltip(toolTipSettings);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

[Here's a bootply to show code in action](http://www.bootply.com/W7WwIZAyFj)

Comment: This may be of some use to you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107002/bootstrap-3-popover-and-tooltip-on-the-same-element

Comment: Yeah I've seen that but it doesn't help me unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around a bit with your Bootply, I see your problem. You are placing your tooltip on the left of your `.myPopover` element. However, this element currently has 100% width of the scrren, meaning your tooptip appears to the left and off of the screen. It **IS** showing up, you just can't see it.

Just to get you started, adding this CSS lets you see it in action:

```
.myPopover {
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: auto;     //Margin left and right to auto to center element
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 200px;          //Set width so it doesn't consume 100%
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

[Updated Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Kz7sZqcLEW)

Comment: @DarrenSweeney It happens to the best of us haha. It took me a bit of tinkering to realize what was going on too. You usually don't suspect something that simple!